# Fallback message for empty object meteor/react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I would like to show a message if there aren't objects to be returned. Something like: 'currently there are no customers available'.
I tried to tinker a bit with **Object.getOwnPropertyNames()** but could not get it working because the mapping function does not being called. I'm not sure where to put this check, inside the rendering function, in the with tracker or render call inside the template.

I use Meteor/react and my code looks like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {withTracker} from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

class ArchiveCustomerOverview extends Component {
  renderCustomerList() {
    return this.props.users.map( user => {
        return(
            <div className="row" key={user._id}>
                <Link to={}>
                    <span className="medium-1">{user.profile.name}</span>
                    <span className="medium-4">{user.profile.company}</span>
                    <span className="medium-3">{user.profile.phone}</span>
                    <span className="medium-3">{user.emails[0].address}</span>
                </Link>
            </div>
        )
    });
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="list-overview">
                <div className="list-wrapper">
                    <div className="list-box clear">
                        {this.renderCustomerList()}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
export default withTracker( (props) => {
  Meteor.subscribe('users');
   return { 
    users: Meteor.users.find({
        'profile.isArchived': 0,
        'roles.customers'       : 'customer'
    }).fetch() 
  };
})(ArchiveCustomerOverview);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check on the number of users before you render them like this:

```
  renderCustomerList() {
    if (this.props.users.length === 0) {
      return (<div>Currently there are no customers available</div>)
    }
    return this.props.users.map( user => {
```

But a word of warning: you may not get what you want from the users collection - for security reasons it is treated differently from other collections.